# imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo conflicts with optional requirement method in protocol 'UIImagePickerControllerDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode7

Here is the full error:

> Objective-C method 'imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:' provided by method 
>       'imagePickerController(_ :didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' 
>       conflicts with optional requirement method 'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)'
>        in protocol 'UIImagePickerControllerDelegate'

It occurs on the first of this function in my ViewController.swift file:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]){
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        ImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        ImageView.image = pickedImage
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I am trying to follow this tutorial: http://www.codingexplorer.com/choosing-images-with-uiimagepickercontroller-in-swift/

from the error method, I gather that there is a method didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo that it is getting from the imagePickerController base class and it doesn't like that I'm trying to overwrite it. But thats all I know. All of the imagePickerController functions I find online look like this. What am I doing wrong?

I am using Xcode 7, if that makes a difference. ]

[image: Screenshot 1]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The correct function head is:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    <#code#>
}
```

Note the `String` instead of `NSObject` in the declaration of the info dictionary.

I am not sure to why the docs are saying that you have to write `NSObject`, but `String` is the correct one.

If you implement any protocol methods I would recommend using the auto completion of Xcode to make sure that you don't run into problems like this.

[image]

I am unsure where Xcode gets that auto completion from but it appears to always be in sync with the actual compiler which in the end is the one thing you have to worry about rather than some online apple docs! Especially in times when the frameworks are constantly changing and even the language itself is under development.

Comment: Your answer fixed my problem, although XCode 8 autocomplete caused it, so autocomplete can be wrong as well. See my answer below

Comment: Swift 3:         'func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {'

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Xcode 7, you may be targeting iOS 9, then, in which the method signature changed slightly from:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
```

to:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
```

The `NSObject` has changed to `String`.

In **Swift 3** it changed to

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is format of **didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo** delegate of UIImagePickerController:

```
 public func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
```

In your case use **String** instead of **NSObject** in function parameter.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue writing an extension to UIImagePickerControllerDelegate in XCode 8

XCode 8 Autocomplete produces a method signature with an underscore for the first parameter. This creates a segmentation fault in the Swift compiler. Removing the underscore fixes the issue.

```
// CRASH SegFault 11
@objc protocol MyDelegate: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

}
extension MyDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        // code
    }
}


// DOESN'T CRASH 
@objc protocol MyDelegate: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

}

extension MyDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        // code
    }
}
```